# Setting "Program Files" as a default installation directory in the Qt Installer Framework

Tags: c++, qt, qt-installer

In the Qt Installer Framework, all of the demos have `TargetDir` specification that (for Windows) place the application in, e.g., `C:\InstallationDirectory`. How can I have it default to Program Files?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Installer>
    <Name>Your application</Name>
    <Version>1.2.3</Version>
    <Title>Your application Installer</Title>
    <Publisher>Your vendor</Publisher>
    <StartMenuDir>Super App</StartMenuDir>
    <TargetDir>@RootDir@InstallationDirectory</TargetDir>
</Installer>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no option for this, but you can create use the Component Scripting interface to set the installation directory, as described [here](http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/interest/2013-January/005679.html).

First, in your `packages/com.myorg.myapp/meta/package.xml` file, include this reference to the script file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package>
    ...
    <Script>installscript.qs</Script>
</Package>
```

The `installscript.qs` file, which should be in the same directory as `package.xml`, should be the following:

```
function Component()
{
     var programFiles = installer.environmentVariable("ProgramFiles");
     if (programFiles != "")
         installer.setValue("TargetDir", programFiles + "/MyPath");
}
```

Now the installer framework will suggest `C:\Program Files\MyPath` or `C:\Program Files (x86)\MyPath`, as needed.

Finally, if you want to allow installation paths with spaces (like `C:\Program Files\MyPath`), you need to enable that specifically in `config/config.xml` by adding this line:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Installer>
     ...
     <AllowSpaceInPath>true</AllowSpaceInPath>
</Installer>
```

Comment: To be able to install my 64-bit application to 'Program Files' rather than to 'Program Files (86)' I had to use `var programFiles = installer.environmentVariable("ProgramFilesW6432");`.

Comment: That is "ProgramW6432" on my machine (Windows 10)

Answer (score 7):

**From Qt Installer Framework >= 3.0**

You can now use the `ApplicationsDir` variable, and it'll default to `C:\Program Files` on Windows, `/opt` on Linux and `/Applications` on OS X.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Installer>
    ...
    <TargetDir>@ApplicationsDir@/InstallationDirectory</TargetDir>
</Installer>
```

Reference: http://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/scripting.html#applications-directory-on-windows